# cacheing chunks across different document types

Tags: r, knitr

I am using the 'preview' version of RStudio and
I have an `Rmd` file that I use to generate html, `pdf` and `docx` documents. I have set up my options like this:

```
opts_chunk$set(cache=TRUE, comment="",message=FALSE, warning = FALSE)
```

`cache=TRUE` works well when I try to re-create a document of the same extension `eg.htm` but if I try to use the same `Rmd` file to create a `pdf` or `docx` document, then the cached figures are not re-used and executes very slow. Is there a way to re-use the cached figures for the different type of documents? Please consider the following minimal example:

```
{r,echo=FALSE}
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(cache=TRUE, comment="",message=FALSE, warning = FALSE)


{r, echo=FALSE}
   plot(cars)
```

If I choose the `knit html` option it creates the html document and re-uses the code but clicking on `knit pdf`, `cache=TRUE` gets ignored. Obviously with this minimal example is not noticeable but using my file with about 30 graphics it totally slows down.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the **rmarkdown** package sets different chunk options for different output formats, e.g. PDF output uses the chunk option `dev='pdf'`, and HTML output uses `dev='png'`. Changes in chunk options will invalidate cache.

One thing you can do is to create different cache directories for different output formats, e.g.

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
local({
  to = opts_knit$get('rmarkdown.pandoc.to')  # output format
  opts_chunk$set(cache.path = paste('cache', to, sep = '_'))
})
```
````

Note this will only make sure caching works for output formats separately. You cannot share the cache database across different output formats, unless you set identical chunk options for all output formats, which is not practical, so I guess you have to accept this sub-optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try cache=1 instead of cache=T.
Please see [the cache invalidation rules](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/2b3e617a700f6d236e22873cfff6cbc3568df568/R/block.R#L96-L100).